# How I can send message from server to client using the port?

Tags: c#, client-server, tcp

I am using Tcplistener to listen on a port for requests. When the requests come in from the client I want to know the client ip making the request.
the problem is : the server and all client take the same Ip

so I decided to send massage from server to client by port ... I search a lot on google But I did not knew how I can send message from server to client using the port ? so can any body help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The clients are not listening for *incoming* connections, so the only way for the server to send a message to a client is by using an *existing* connection, that was previously established by the client.

You don't have to specify the port number when sending a message on an existing connection, your server can just use:

```
Socket handlerSocket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
// a connection is now established, "handlerSocket" can be used for both receiving and sending messages
handlerSocket.Send(...);
```

Your clients currently send data and immediately close the connection though, you'll have to modify them to read data from the `NetworkStream` in order to receive anything.

There are tons of tutorials available, I think you just googled the wrong keywords. Have you tried something like `c# chat tutorial`?

Answer (score 0):

You are running them all in the same computer. That is why the IP is always the same.

SOP for this kind of thing is to have two ports: a control port and a data port.

The way this works is:

- The control port is used to initiate the connection.
- Upon successful connection, the server and the client negotiate a set of ports to be used for the data (local server data port and remote client data port).
- The server establishes a connection to the remote client data port from the local server data port.
- The client issues a request for data (e.g. command) through the control port.
- The server sends the information back through the data port.

Comment: FTP uses this so the control port isn't occupied during large file transfers - but even on the control port, data flows both ways. For simple communication you don't need two active connections to have a conversation, regardless of whether you're on the same computer.

Comment: If you look at the snapshot @C.Evenhuis, you will notice he is trying to do just that, a file transfer.

Comment: You have a point there, if two-way communication _during_ a file transfer is required, your solution would solve that.